# ESP32 heap problem

Tags: esp32, heap

I wrote a simple C++ program (just main.cpp and corresponding platform.io files & libraries) to get BME280 sensor readings. It worked fine until I decided to use good programming practices, using header files and separating the read function from main.cpp, I get a heap error, stated below:

```
CORRUPT HEAP: Bad head at 0x3ffb8444. Expected 0xabba1234 got 0x3ffb84c4
abort() was called at PC 0x40083b99 on core 1

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace:
0x400857f0:0x3ffb1aa0
0x40085a65:0x3ffb1ac0
0x40083b99:0x3ffb1ae0
0x40083cc5:0x3ffb1b10
0x400d90a3:0x3ffb1b30
0x400d55bd:0x3ffb1df0
0x400d5558:0x3ffb1e40
0x4008a0f1:0x3ffb1e70
0x40081dee:0x3ffb1e90
0x40083a91:0x3ffb1eb0
0x4000bec7:0x3ffb1ed0
0x400e89b5:0x3ffb1ef0
0x400d13ab:0x3ffb1f10
0x400d0f75:0x3ffb1f30
0x400d3ba9:0x3ffb1fb0
0x40086a75:0x3ffb1fd0

Rebooting...
```

Any ideas on that?

By the way, I also used pointers for both the function and the variable passed to it, to no avail.

I also tried a series of combinations with the libraries I am using - Adafruit BME280 and Adafruit Unified Sensor.

Going back to having all the code in one file works...

Thanks

My code:

```cxx
//main.cpp
#include <sensor_readings.h>
#include <settings.h>

void refresh_readings();  // Declare in the header so that the compiler knows about it before it is called in loop()

Adafruit_BME280 bme; // I2C

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  bool status;

  // (you can also pass in a Wire library object like &Wire2)
  status = bme.begin(0x76);
  if (!status) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  void (*fcnPtr)(Adafruit_BME280){ &refresh_readings };
  (*fcnPtr)(bme);
  //refresh_readings(bme);
  delay(4000);
}

;platformio.ini
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
lib_deps = 
    Adafruit_Sensor
    adafruit/Adafruit Unified Sensor@1.1.4
    adafruit/Adafruit BME280 Library@^2.2.2
upload_port = /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
monitor_port = /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
monitor_speed = 9600

//sensor_readings.cpp
#include <sensor_readings.h>
#include <settings.h>


void refresh_readings(Adafruit_BME280 bme) {
  float f_temperature;
  float f_humidity;
  float f_pressure;
  float f_altitude;

  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

  f_temperature = bme.readTemperature();
  f_humidity = bme.readHumidity();
  f_pressure = bme.readPressure() / 100.0F;
  f_altitude = bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA);

  // Temperature

  Serial.print(f_temperature);
  Serial.println(" °C");

  // Humidity
  Serial.print(f_humidity);
  Serial.println(" %");

  // Pressure
  Serial.print(f_pressure);
  Serial.println(" hPa");

  // Appx altitude
  Serial.print(f_altitude);
  Serial.println(" m");   
  
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  Serial.println("------------");   
}

//sensor_readings.h
#ifndef SENSOR_READINGS_H

    #define SENSOR_READINGS_H

    #include <Arduino.h>
    #include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
    #include <Adafruit_BME280.h>

    #define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA (1013.25)

    void refresh_readings(Adafruit_BME280 bme);

#endif

//settings.h
#ifndef SETTINGS_H
    #define SETTINGS_H
    #define LED_BUILTIN 2   // This is valid for my devkit
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple problems with your code.

```
void refresh_readings();  // Declare in the header so that
                          // the compiler knows about it
                          // before it is called in loop()
```

This is a lie! Don't tell your compiler there's a `refresh_readings` function that takes no arguments when you haven't defined one. Remove that line, you already have the function declaration in your header.

```
void (*fcnPtr)(Adafruit_BME280){ &refresh_readings };
(*fcnPtr)(bme);
```

This is just a very convoluted way of typing:

```
refresh_readings(bme);
```

So just use the normal function call syntax.

The main issue as far as I can tell though is that you are copying the `bme` object when passing it to the readings function, which is not advisable in general for this sort of object (they represent a piece of hardware that you can't really copy). That class in particular has a bunch of pointer members, a destructor that deletes them, but no copy constructor as far as I can tell, which [is a bad thing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Change your function to this signature (both in the header and the C++ file):

```
void refresh_readings(Adafruit_BME280& bme);
//                 pass by reference ^
```

And use the normal call syntax (`refresh_readings(bme);`).

Comment: Dear Mat, thank you VERY much for taking your time to answer to my question. It is working now. Regards, Carlos.